# Java method returning two or more generic types

Tags: java, generics

There are a lot of questions regarding Java methods returning generic types, but none of them helped me out so far.

So here's my code:

```
interface DAO<K, T> {
   void    insert(T t);
   void    update(K k, T t);
   void    delete(K k);
   void    delete();
   T       select(K k);
   List<T> select();
}

public class CourseDAO implements DAO<String, Course> {
   public void         insert(Course t) {}
   public void         update(String k, Course t) {}
   public void         delete(String k) {}
   public void         delete() {}
   public Course       select(String k) {}
   public List<Course> select() {}
}

public class StudentDAO implements DAO<Long, Student> {
   public void          insert(Student t) {}
   public void          update(Long k, Student t) {}
   public void          delete(Long k) {}
   public void          delete() {}
   public Student       select(Long k) {}
   public List<Student> select() {}
}

public enum EntityType { COURSE, STUDENT }
```

Now I want a factory method which accepts an `EntityType` parameter and return an instance of `CourseDAO` or `StudentDAO` depending on the parameter value.

I tried the code below without success:

```
public <K,T> DAO<K,T> createDAOFactory(EntityType type) {
   switch (type) {
      case COURSE  : return (K,T) new CourseDAO();  break;
      case STUDENT : return (K,T) new StudentDAO(); break;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Could anyone help me in writing and invoking this method???

Cheers,
Romualdo.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this factory method? As far as I can tell, there can be no sensible way to use such a method (assuming it could compile to begin with).

Comment: If I remove <K,T> from the method signature keeping DAO as a return type and (K,T) from return's it compiles but Eclipse shows the warning: "DAO is a raw type. References to generic type DAO<K,T> should be parameterized".

Comment: Yes, that's one way to make it compile. But how you intend to call this method and use the DAO it returns?

Comment: Btw, the `break;` statements are unreachable and wouldn't compile.

Comment: Instead of creating specific instances of entities DAO in the code I just call the factory method passing what "entity" I want. This way I have a more **object oriented** code creating an interface (software contract) and having all DAO classes implementing this software contract.

Comment: When 2 classes implement the same interface but with different generic arguments, they implement _different_ software contracts, and it does not make sense to use a single factory to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast you're looking for is `(DAO<K,T>)`. But you'll get a warning because generic type erasure makes it unsafe. Another inherent risk in the `switch` factory is that you might forget to create a corresponding `case` when you add a new `EntityType`. A safer alternative would be to redefine `EntityType` with generic types, and let it be the factory. Unfortunately, this isn't possible with proper enums, but you can simulate it like this:

```
abstract class EntityType<K, T> {
    public abstract DAO<K, T> createDAO();

    public static final EntityType<String, Course> COURSE = new EntityType<String, Course>() {
        @Override
        public DAO<String, Course> createDAO() {
            return new CourseDAO();
        }
    };
    public static final EntityType<Long, Student> STUDENT = new EntityType<Long, Student>() {
        @Override
        public DAO<Long, Student> createDAO() {
            return new StudentDAO();
        }
    };
}
```

Or you can use lambdas to reduce the boilerplate:

```
class EntityType<K, T> {
    private final Supplier<DAO<K, T>> constructor;

    private EntityType(Supplier<DAO<K, T>> constructor) {
        this.constructor = constructor;
    }

    public DAO<K, T> createDAO() {
        return constructor.get();
    }

    public static final EntityType<String, Course> COURSE = new EntityType<>(CourseDAO::new);
    public static final EntityType<Long, Student> STUDENT = new EntityType<>(StudentDAO::new);
}
```

Now, instead of calling `createDAOFactory(EntityType.COURSE)`, you would just call `EntityType.COURSE.createDAO()`.

Comment: Hi Shmosel, in your first example, can you please show how the factory would use this abstract class

Comment: @ScaryWombat It **is** the factory. Edited to clarify.

Comment: *you would just call* `EntityType.COURSE.createDAO()`  OK that makes sense

Comment: Now my code runs like this:  `DAO<String, Course> obj = EntityType.COURSE.createDAO();`.  Thanks, shmosel.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do like this?

```
public class StudentDAO<Long,Student> implements DAO<Long, Student> {
    public void          insert(Student t) {}
    public void          update(Long k, Student t) {}
    public void          delete(Long k) {}
    public void          delete() {}
    public Student       select(Long k) {return null;}
    public List<Student> select() {return null;}
}

public <K,T> DAO<K,T>createDAOFactory(EntityType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case COURSE  : return new CourseDAO();
        case STUDENT : return new StudentDAO();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

first answer

you do not need use generics，because Implementation class has specified the type.

```
public DAO createDAOFactory(EntityType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case COURSE  : return new CourseDAO();
        case STUDENT : return new StudentDAO();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks flytosea, I'm doing this way. Plz read my coment on Steven's comment (above).